# Drupal Forms + Civicrm Contributions, Doesn't process Contribution?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, contribution-page

I'm using Drupal 7.43, civicrm 4.7.4., drupal webform 7.x-4.5, and webform civicrm integration 7.x-4.13.

I made a form that would allow users to apply for paid membership.  There are a few pages of civicrm tied fields (asking for name, address, other relevant questions), and then a page that ties to a civicrm contribution page.

However, when I test out the page there is some weirdness with the contribution page.  The form loads settings from the civicrm contribution page, including a button to 'submit contribution'.  Below this is the arrow buttons to go forward or backward on the webform.

When I click just on the button to go forward to the preview page, it goes to the preview page, but the contribution is not processed.  If instead I click on the 'Submit Contribution' button, it acts as though I clicked the 'previous page' button and still doesn't process the contribution.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

I tried out the contribution page without the Drupal form, and it processed the payment.  So I think it's related to the Drupal form. 
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that this has been fixed in updates.  Not sure the exact bug or feature request, but it's worked on our site since I made this question.

Answer (score 2):

See [Payment form broken on CiviCRM 4.7](https://www.drupal.org/node/2661232)

Comment: That's frustrating. Any ideas when it might be fixed or how to use something else?  I installed some civicrm Entities and Entity Forms but don't really know what to do with them.