# ACL for Contribution Page?

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, acl, roles

I'm using Drupal 7.43, and civicrm 4.7.4.  Is it possible to limit access to a contribution page through Civicrm ACL's or Drupal roles?  I want to set up a contribution page for new members to pay an initiation fee, but I don't want members to see it once they pay.

I can set up a drupal block, and have the link to the contribution page in the block, and assign the block to a role of new members who haven't paid the fee yet, and have the block disappear once they do, but they can still go to the url and access the contribution page.

Answer (score 1):

If your payment processor works with webforms possibly you could do it that way.
At least for our configuation we have much better control over the visibility of drupal content rather than civicrm forms.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was originally trying to do, but apparently web forms doesn't work with civicrm 4.7's contribution features yet.  (http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10660/drupal-forms-civicrm-contributions-doesnt-process-contribution/10670#10670)

Comment: That is now sorted

Comment: @petednz-fusion - correct, and that getting fixed helped us set up a couple of good webforms with civicrm integrated contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that would be suitable in some circumstances would be to use cividiscount and hence discount the membership fee by the amount of the initiation fee for existing members